# Magento 2: How to disable / remove Secret Key from Admin URL?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

Magento 2: How to disable / remove Secret Key from Admin URL?

A new secret key is created every time you login to Magento Admin. So, there will be a unique key (32 chars long) for each session of your Magento admin login. This key is appended to the admin URL as http://your-admin-url/key/885453c37b1…adf6588/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Magento 2. Here is how you do it:**

- Login to admin
- Go to Stores -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Security -> Add
  Secret Key to URLs
- Select No
- Save Config
- Click **Cache Management** in top header - One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated
- Click Flush Magento Cache

---

Magento say that they added secret key to URL for CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) Attack Prevention.